# Adding new endpoint to Amazon SNS - Xamarin

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, xamarin.ios, xamarin, amazon-sns

I am working on an `iOS application` using `Xamarin`, and I have a problem with `Amazon's SNS`:

How to register device token to the amazon SNS using AWS token vending service.

Code from https://github.com/xamarin/amazon, doesn't provide **AddPlatformEndpoint()** method, I couldn't create bindings for Amazon SDK for iOS, and Amazon SDK for .NET uses Namespaces that are not available in mono so I can't use it either.

Have someone figure out how to do it? Maybe I should use Amazon's Web API, but I have no idea how to do it (I've tried but couldn't got it working).
I would be very grateful if you give me some sample.